# Написать SQL запрос, который возарвщает клиентов - только у кого за последний месяц каждый день был хотя бы один заказ

Tags: sql

Динамика количества заказов по клиентам ежедневно создававших хотя бы один заказ
У вас есть таблица Orders с колонками order_id (id заказа), created (дата создания заказа, формат datetime), user_id (id клиента, создавшего заказ).
Напишите запрос, который возвращает:
Клиентов - только у кого за последний месяц каждый день был хотя бы один заказ.
Попробывала так, но не знаю, как поставить условие на каждый день?
`введите сюда код`

```
SELECT user_id FROM Orders
WHERE created >= date(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) and order_id!= '' and 
Group BY user_id
```

Comment: Считаете количество дат у клиента в заданном промежутке. Сравниваете с количеством дат в этом промежутке вообще. Если не равно - значит. клиент сачковал. и его не показывать.

Comment: @Akina спасибо большое

Comment: @Anika,  а можете написать, как это будет выглядить, я что-то запуталась - пока посчитала SELECT user_id  FROM Orders
WHERE created >= date(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) and order_id!= '' and COUNT(DISTINCT(created)) == DATEDIFF(NOW(), NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
Group BY user_id

Comment: ... и ещё плюс один... хотя зависит от того, что тут разумеется под термином "последний месяц". Вот по состоянию на сегодня - это с 1 по 30 сентября? или с 29 сентября по 28 октября? или сегодня не считаем, и берём с 28 сентября по 27 октября?

Comment: @Akina c 28 сентября по 27 октября

Comment: Ну вот на основании сегодняшней даты считаете эти две даты и соответственно количество дней между ними. Не забываете прибавить один день.

Comment: @Akina SELECT user_id  FROM Orders
WHERE COUNT(DISTINCT(created))==DATEDIFF(NOW(), NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH+1)  почему-то не работает

Comment: Наверное, потому, что надо работать с датами, а не с датой-временем. Т.е. и вместо NOW() следует использовать CURRENT_DATE, и из `created` выстригать чисто дату. Ну и к дате нельзя прибавлять число (единицу) - дата будет преобразована в число, и получится ерунда. Единицу надо плюсить уже после вычисления количества дней. Ну и, поскольку надо всё же посчитать количество уникальных дней покупок - нужна группировка. А сравнивать надо с посчитанным количеством, что делается вовсе даже не во WHERE.